# Horners Scheme Binary to Decimal Conversion

Tags: binary, decimal

Using Horner's scheme, represent (evaluate) the binary unsigned whole number 11001101 in decimal. I got 410 I just want to make sure its right.

Answer (score 0):

11001101

Horner's Scheme:

((((((((1*2 + 1)2 + 0)2 + 0)2 + 1)2 + 1)2 + 0)2 + 1

1*2=2+1=3*2=6+0=6*2=12+0=12*2=24+1=25*2=50+1=51*2=102+0=102*2=204+1=205

11001101 (binary) = 205 (decimal)

NOTE: You do not multiply the last 1 because the 2 exponent is actually 0 there, and 2^0=1.